# Nginx serving only index page in case ssl enabled

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure `nginx.conf` for ssl configuration. My UI static content is inside `/usr/share/nginx/html`. Earlier I was able to load all the pages over `http` but when I enable `https` it is serving only `index` page rest other pages are showing `404 Not Found` nginx 404 default page. I do not have any `sites-available` folder present anywhere. Looks like I am missing any minor configuration. Please help me on where am I making the mistake. I am using `nginx:alpine` docker image as base. All static pages/content are present under `/usr/share/nginx/html` and served at `/**` and backend is served using api call with uri `/api/**`

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```js
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/nginx-certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/nginx.key;
  server_name _;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass https://my-aws-ec2-instance.com;
  }
  location /em {
    proxy_pass https://my-aws-s3-instance.com;
  }
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```js
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding `try_files`, it worked.

```js
location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Looks like on nginx retry it pass, but not sure if it create another cascading issue.